# How to add blank rows to separate between data in PHPexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want add a blank rows between the data to separated it on PHPExcel

the data is like this picture
[image: the data is like this picture]

i want to separate jhonny and barry with blank rows
How's the code to do that ?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

check unique ID of user and separate by push blank array or null value.

```
$id= null;
```

foreach ($variable as $key => $value) {

```
if ($id == $value->id || $id == null) {
    $insert[] = array();    //insert data
}esle{
    $insert[] = array();//balank array
    $insert[] = array();    //insert data
}

$id = $value->id;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A very rough example, but hope you'll understand the logic.

```
$user_id = 'no_possible_duplicate_user_id';

foreach(){
 if($user_id != $current_iteration_user_id){

   //code for new row here as a separator

 }

 // here is the code for displaying each record on an excel row

 $user_id = $current_iteration_user_id;
}
```